# Issue in MSI Launch Condition for detecting currently installed Excel version

Tags: windows-installer

I have a MSI for installing an Excel AddIn.

This MSI has worked correctly on a number of machines till now (both 64 bit and 32 bit machines running Windows 7, Windows Vista or Windows XP) but recently a launch condition falsely failed for one of the user.

MSI was prepared using Visual Studio 2010 installer project on a 32 bit Windows XP machine.

User is trying to install it on Windows 7 64 bit machine with Excel 2007 SP2 (32 bit) installed.

The launch condition is to determine the currently installed Excel version.
For this:

1. I have a registry search action with following parameters

   ```
   Property: EXCEL
   RegKeY: Software\Classes\Excel.Application\CurVer
   Root: vsdrrHKLM
   Value:
   ```
2. And the launch condition is `EXCEL = "Excel.Application.12" OR EXCEL = "Excel.Application.14"`

On the user's machine I have already confirmed that:

1. The registry value at 'HKLM\Software\Classes\Excel.Application\CurVer' is 'Excel.Application.12'
2. The msi logs indicates that this value was correctly read

The logs look like:

```
Action 15:42:58: ProgressForm. Dialog created
Action ended 15:42:58: ProgressForm. Return value 1.
MSI (c) (AC:28) [15:42:58:401]: Doing action: ExecuteAction
Action 15:42:58: ExecuteAction. 
Action start 15:42:58: ExecuteAction.
MSI (c) (AC:28) [15:42:58:410]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SECONDSEQUENCE property. Its value is '1'.
MSI (c) (AC:28) [15:42:58:413]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (AC:28) [15:42:58:416]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (c) (AC:28) [15:42:58:419]: Switching to server: TARGETDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\" _F6F7C451BA1841F0B59F5BF6C3620B2B="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Data\" _B87F203625174B9894BB9AAD7BBA6EAB="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Bin\" _6448E393C853494F8BBDC9D2FA0DA440="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyCompany\" _BA6D696DE1324CDF936304F630FC10AD="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MyCompany\MySoftware\" _77B6D7C007D440959AF59826EEB28541="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Data\LOGS\" _4AE2CF68991D4AADBC1984A3B6A685D2="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Data\DB\" _0E7ED596C9F747DB961B97EBE7D8CA47="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Doc\" EXCEL2007="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\" EXCEL="Excel.Application.12" VSDNETURLMSG="This setup requires the .NET Framework version 2.0.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Fram
MSI (s) (74:78) [15:42:58:430]: Running installation inside multi-package transaction H:\MySoftware\MySoftware.msi
MSI (s) (74:78) [15:42:58:433]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:42:58:439]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:42:58:442]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:42:58:444]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: H:\MySoftware\MySoftware.msi
           ******* Action: INSTALL
           ******* CommandLine: **********
//A lot of other stuff

MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:43:10:824]: Doing action: AppSearch
Action 15:43:10: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
Action start 15:43:10: AppSearch.
MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:43:10:838]: Skipping AppSearch action: already done on client side
Action ended 15:43:10: AppSearch. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:43:10:844]: Doing action: FindRelatedProducts
Action 15:43:10: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
Action start 15:43:10: FindRelatedProducts.
MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:43:10:855]: Skipping FindRelatedProducts action: already done on client side
Action ended 15:43:10: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 0.
MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:43:10:861]: Skipping action: ERRCA_CANCELNEWERVERSION (condition is false)
MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:43:10:866]: Doing action: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions
Action 15:43:10: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions. 
Action start 15:43:10: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions.
MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:43:10:890]: Creating MSIHANDLE (27) of type 790542 for thread 4344
MSI (s) (74:E0) [15:43:10:893]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI9C72.tmp, Entrypoint: VsdLaunchConditions
MSI (s) (74!34) [15:43:11:441]: Creating MSIHANDLE (28) of type 790531 for thread 6708
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:445] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Custom Action is starting...
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:451] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: CoInitializeEx - COM initialization Apartment Threaded...
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:456] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Enumerating table using SQL statement: 'SELECT * FROM `_VsdLaunchCondition`'
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:460] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Calling MsiGetActiveDatabase...
MSI (s) (74!34) [15:43:11:464]: Creating MSIHANDLE (29) of type 790541 for thread 6708
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:467] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiDatabaseOpenViewW - Prepare Database to view table...
MSI (s) (74!34) [15:43:11:471]: Creating MSIHANDLE (30) of type 790540 for thread 6708
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:474] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: TMsiViewExecute - Open Database view on table...
MSI (s) (74!34) [15:43:11:478]: Creating MSIHANDLE (31) of type 790531 for thread 6708
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:482] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Checking a launch condition...
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:485] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Getting the condition to evaluate...
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:489] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Fetching value...
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:492] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: MsiRecordGetStringW - Getting value from column '1'...
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:497] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Evaluating condition 'VSDFXAvailable'...
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:500] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: RESULT:  Condition is true. Nothing more to do.
MSI (s) (74!34) [15:43:11:504]: Closing MSIHANDLE (31) of type 790531 for thread 6708
MSI (s) (74!34) [15:43:11:508]: Closing MSIHANDLE (30) of type 790540 for thread 6708
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:512] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Custom Action succeeded.
INFO   : [10/25/2012 15:43:11:518] [VsdLaunchConditions                     ]: Custom Action completed with return code: '0'
MSI (s) (74!34) [15:43:11:522]: Closing MSIHANDLE (29) of type 790541 for thread 6708
MSI (s) (74!34) [15:43:11:525]: Closing MSIHANDLE (28) of type 790531 for thread 6708
MSI (s) (74:E0) [15:43:11:530]: Closing MSIHANDLE (27) of type 790542 for thread 4344
Action ended 15:43:11: VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (74:F8) [15:43:11:538]: Doing action: LaunchConditions
Action 15:43:11: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
//Few more lines

Action ended 15:43:13: LaunchConditions. Return value 3.
Action ended 15:43:13: INSTALL. Return value 3.
//some other traces

MSI (c) (AC:04) [15:43:16:896]: Custom Action Manager thread ending.
Property(C): UpgradeCode = {9FC0F443-EECC-4C3B-939E-D033349C22BA}
Property(C): TARGETDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware
Property(C): _F6F7C451BA1841F0B59F5BF6C3620B2B = C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Data\
Property(C): _B87F203625174B9894BB9AAD7BBA6EAB = C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Bin\
Property(C): ProgramMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
Property(C): _6448E393C853494F8BBDC9D2FA0DA440 = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MySoftware\
Property(C): _BA6D696DE1324CDF936304F630FC10AD = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\MySoftware\
Property(C): WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
Property(C): SystemFolder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(C): SourceDir = H:\MySoftware\
Property(C): _77B6D7C007D440959AF59826EEB28541 = C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Data\LOGS\
Property(C): _4AE2CF68991D4AADBC1984A3B6A685D2 = C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Data\DB\
Property(C): _0E7ED596C9F747DB961B97EBE7D8CA47 = C:\Program Files (x86)\MySoftware\Doc\
Property(C): VSDFXAvailable = TRUE
Property(C): VSDFrameworkVersion = v2.0
Property(C): VSDAllowLaterFrameworkVersions = False
Property(C): EXCEL2007 = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\
Property(C): EXCEL = Excel.Application.12
Property(C): ProductName = MySoftware
Property(C): ProductCode = {04835711-7FDB-4B00-9A39-6C6776D9900A}
Property(C): ProductVersion = 1.31.2012
Property(C): Manufacturer = MyCompany
Property(C): ARPHELPLINK = http://www.MyCompany.com/
Property(C): ARPCONTACT = MyCompany
Property(C): ARPURLINFOABOUT = http://www.MyCompany.com/
Property(C): ProductLanguage = 1033
Property(C): SecureCustomProperties = PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED;NEWERPRODUCTFOUND
Property(C): RedirectedDllSupport = 2
Property(C): VersionNT = 601
Property(C): VSDNETURLMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version 2.0.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.  The .NET Framework can be obtained from the web.  Would you like to do this now?
Property(C): VSDIISMSG = This setup requires Internet Information Server 5.1 or higher and Windows XP or higher.  This setup cannot be installed on Windows 2000.  Please install Internet Information Server or a newer operating system and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDUIANDADVERTISED = This advertised application will not be installed because it might be unsafe. Contact your administrator to change the installation user interface option of the package to basic.
Property(C): VSDNETMSG = This setup requires the .NET Framework version 2.0.  Please install the .NET Framework and run this setup again.
Property(C): VSDINVALIDURLMSG = The specified path '[2]' is unavailable. The Internet Information Server might not be running or the path exists and is redirected to another machine. Please check the status of this virtual directory in the Internet Services Manager.
Property(C): VSDVERSIONMSG = Unable to install because a newer version of this product is already installed.
Property(C): FolderForm_AllUsers = ALL
Property(C): FolderForm_AllUsersVisible = 1
Property(C): DefaultUIFont = VsdDefaultUIFont.524F4245_5254_5341_4C45_534153783400
Property(C): MaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(C): AdminMaintenanceForm_Action = Repair
Property(C): ErrorDialog = ErrorDialog
Property(C): SFF_UpFldrBtn = UpFldrBtn
Property(C): SFF_NewFldrBtn = NewFldrBtn
Property(C): WelcomeForm_NextArgs = FolderForm
Property(C): FolderForm_PrevArgs = WelcomeForm
Property(C): FolderForm_NextArgs = ConfirmInstallForm
Property(C): ConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = FolderForm
Property(C): AdminWelcomeForm_NextArgs = AdminFolderForm
Property(C): AdminFolderForm_PrevArgs = AdminWelcomeForm
Property(C): AdminFolderForm_NextArgs = AdminConfirmInstallForm
Property(C): AdminConfirmInstallForm_PrevArgs = AdminFolderForm
Property(C): WindowsFolder_x86_VC.F1DD796A_B984_3DCA_A68D_6B352BDC86F3 = C:\Windows\
Property(C): SystemFolder_x86_VC.F1DD796A_B984_3DCA_A68D_6B352BDC86F3 = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
Property(C): ALLUSERS = 2
Property(C): DirectoryTable100_x86.F1DD796A_B984_3DCA_A68D_6B352BDC86F3 = DirectoryTable
Property(C): MsiLogFileLocation = H:\MySoftware\.\msilog.txt
Property(C): PackageCode = {ABF9C77A-61D2-49AF-BD7F-F55CE2567525}
Property(C): ProductState = -1
Property(C): PackagecodeChanging = 1
Property(C): RestrictedUserControl = 1
Property(C): CURRENTDIRECTORY = H:\MySoftware
Property(C): CLIENTUILEVEL = 0
Property(C): CLIENTPROCESSID = 7340
Property(C): VersionDatabase = 200
Property(C): VersionMsi = 5.00
Property(C): VersionNT64 = 601
Property(C): WindowsBuild = 7601
Property(C): ServicePackLevel = 1
Property(C): ServicePackLevelMinor = 0
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 1
Property(C): WindowsVolume = C:\
Property(C): System64Folder = C:\Windows\system32\
Property(C): RemoteAdminTS = 1
Property(C): TempFolder = C:\Users\U060597\AppData\Local\Temp\
Property(C): ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
Property(C): CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
Property(C): ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\
Property(C): CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files\
Property(C): AppDataFolder = C:\Users\U060597\AppData\Roaming\
Property(C): FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\U060597\Favorites\
Property(C): NetHoodFolder = C:\Users\U060597\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
Property(C): PersonalFolder = C:\
Property(C): PrintHoodFolder = C:\Users\U060597\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts\
Property(C): RecentFolder = C:\Users\U060597\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\
Property(C): SendToFolder = C:\Users\U060597\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
Property(C): TemplateFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
Property(C): CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
Property(C): LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\U060597\AppData\Local\
Property(C): MyPicturesFolder = C:\My Pictures\
Property(C): AdminToolsFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
Property(C): StartupFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
Property(C): StartMenuFolder = C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
Property(C): DesktopFolder = C:\Users\Public\Desktop\
Property(C): FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
Property(C): GPTSupport = 1
Property(C): OLEAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): ShellAdvtSupport = 1
Property(C): MsiAMD64 = 6
Property(C): Msix64 = 6
Property(C): Intel = 6
Property(C): PhysicalMemory = 12279
Property(C): VirtualMemory = 18474
Property(C): LogonUser = u060597
Property(C): UserSID = S-1-5-21-1715567821-1004336348-725345543-486654
Property(C): UserLanguageID = 2057
Property(C): ComputerName = WR8DW1T3
Property(C): SystemLanguageID = 2057
Property(C): ScreenX = 1920
Property(C): ScreenY = 1080
Property(C): CaptionHeight = 22
Property(C): BorderTop = 1
Property(C): BorderSide = 1
Property(C): TextHeight = 16
Property(C): TextInternalLeading = 3
Property(C): ColorBits = 32
Property(C): TTCSupport = 1
Property(C): Time = 15:43:17
Property(C): Date = 25/10/2012
Property(C): MsiNetAssemblySupport = 4.0.30319.1
Property(C): MsiWin32AssemblySupport = 6.1.7601.17514
Property(C): AdminUser = 1
Property(C): MsiRunningElevated = 1
Property(C): Privileged = 1
Property(C): USERNAME = user
Property(C): COMPANYNAME = UserCompany
Property(C): DATABASE = C:\Users\U060597\AppData\Local\Temp\5c64805.msi
Property(C): OriginalDatabase = H:\MySoftware\MySoftware.msi
Property(C): SOURCEDIR = H:\MySoftware\
Property(C): VersionHandler = 5.00
Property(C): UILevel = 5
Property(C): ACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): EXECUTEACTION = INSTALL
Property(C): VSDFxConfigFile = C:\Users\U060597\AppData\Local\Temp\CFG4C2A.tmp
Property(C): ROOTDRIVE = C:\
Property(C): CostingComplete = 1
Property(C): OutOfDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): OutOfNoRbDiskSpace = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceAvailable = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRequired = 0
Property(C): PrimaryVolumeSpaceRemaining = 0
Property(C): INSTALLLEVEL = 1
=== Logging stopped: 25/10/2012  15:43:17 ===
```

As can be seen from above logs, property 'EXCEL' is correctly set and still launch condition fails. Also MSI is running with elevated permissions.

Does anyone has any idea of what might be going wrong here?
I am fairly new to the world of deployment and will really appreciate any help in this regard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say 100% without seeing the entire log but what appears to be happening to me:

1) You start the install and get through the dialogs.

2) The installer starts installing and throws an error message regarding excel.

3) The installer exits.

The LaunchConditions standard action is scheduled for both the Install UI sequence and the Install Execute sequence.   When the UI runs the AppSearch action is fired and the property is set.

However, the EXCEL property isn't listed in the SecureCustomProperties property.  Therefore when the installer switches over the Execute sequence the value becomes null.  Windows Installer doesn't run the AppSearch action again the execute sequence so it stays null.

However, LaunchConditions standard action is ran and the expression evaluates to false aborting the install.

This theory can be proven by reading the entire log file and noting when the actions fire.  Another way to test the theory is to run the MSI from an elevated command prompt.  In that scenario SecureCustomProperties has no effect and the property set in the InstallUI will carry over to the InstallExecute sequence.

Finally, it should be noted that Visual Studio Deployment Projects are, honestly, horrible.  So much that Microsoft removed them from Visual Studio 2012.  I would stop investing any more time in this tool and use Windows Installer XML or InstallShield Limited Edition instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your advise for avoiding VS is well taken. We have migrating to WIX in our road-map but for now we are struck with VS. Regarding your answer, is it possible for the msi to fail, in the way you suspect, on a specific machine while correctly working on others? Also what extra effect does elevated cmd prompt has as opposed to running MSI with elevated permissions (as suggested by logs, MSI is running with elevated permissions)? I have added the logs for just before LaunchConditions is fired for Execute sequence. I can notice that Appsearch was skipped!(don't understand why)

Comment: Also, Is there any system setting (may be some permission change..) that you are aware of that has the same effect as if the MSI is running from elevated cmnd prmpt (thus avoiding the need for opening a cmnd prmpt first)?

Comment: After reading more about MSIs on the Internet, I think I now understand that AppSearch was skipped on the 'server' side as client had already provided the values to server (as can be seen in 'Switching to server' log). But properties listed for server does not contain 'EXCEL' property...Now I understand this is the reason of failure of launch condition but why didn't it pick up the passed property?

Comment: Because the property isn't listed in the SecureCustomProperties property.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Following it I have found EnableUserControl policy which solves this issue though I understand that SecureCustomProperties is recommended over it

Comment: Do you really expect your customers to deploy a group policy setting in order to make an installer work?

Comment: I only expect it to be a temp wrkarnd on that one particular machine till we release a new installer addressing this issue

Comment: Have you considered just running the installer from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: I will propose both the workarounds for the time being and let their IT department take a call...